# Programmatically import new composer from template to project using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I am trying to find information about how to programmatically import new composer from template, but it is impossible.

There is a lot of information how to print the composer to image, but not save it in the project *.qgs.

Has anyone got any experience of loading new composer to project QGIS and open it from list "Print composers"?

Answer (score 6):

This is solve for me.

```
myFile = os.path.join('r:/Graf/_temp/Templates/', 'template.qpt')
myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
myTemplateFile.close()
myDocument = QDomDocument()
myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
newcomp = self.iface.createNewComposer()
newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
```