# Close composer window with Pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I would like to load new composers from template files (*.pqt) when I open my plugin.

I managed to do it using this helpful post 
[Programmatically import new composer from template to project using pyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157807/programmatically-import-new-composer-from-template-to-project-using-pyqgis)

But as explain in QGIS API doc, when using createNewComposer, the composer window will be shown and activated.

Is there a way to automatically close the composer window, then loading template would be 'transparent' for plugin user ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little bit late but I had the same problem and I figured this out (assuming you want to close the first composer):

```
activeComposer = iface.activeComposers()
composer = activeComposer[0]
composerWindow = composer.composerWindow()
composerWindow.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to match the code from your linked answer:

```
newcomp = self.iface.createNewComposer()
newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
newcomp.composerWindow().close()
```

And as proof that the composer itself hasn't been deleted.

```
newcomp.composerWindow().show()
```

Makes the window reappear. Test in `2.18.2`