# Showing QgsComposition created in QGIS Python console

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to develop a similar script to [How to make serial maps from template?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/115636/36886). I'd like to modify elements in the composition programmatically for each map that I want to print. In developing this I'd like to see the elements I'm modifying in the console without printing off the map. I was expecting to see a new print composer window open when I ran the below code from the QGIS console in `2.18.2`, but nothing happens (no error message appears either).

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
def loadPrintComposerTemplate(template):
    '''Load a print composer template from provided filename argument
    
    Args:
        template: readable .qpt template filename
        
    Returns:
        myComposition: a QgsComposition loaded from the provided template
        mapSettings: a QgsMapSettings object associated with myComposition'''
    mapSettings = QgsMapSettings()
    myComposition = QgsComposition(mapSettings)
    # Load template from filename
    with open(template, 'r') as templateFile:
        myTemplateContent = templateFile.read()
    
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    return myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument), mapSettings
composer, mapSet = loadPrintComposerTemplate(template)
```

Is there a way to make the print composer appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the [new composer](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a745197225d791f2e95034ed035e98a61)

```
from qgis.utils import iface
newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
```

Load the template into the composer

```
newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
```

Has been taken from [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157807/programmatically-import-new-composer-from-template-to-project-using-pyqgis). Works in `2.18.2`

Comment: Based on a reading of the documents one might think that loading the template into a `QgsComposition` and then using `newcomp.setComposition(myComposition)` would produce the same results. But I'm noting missing elements on the composer page, and the `Items` list is empty in the composer window

Comment: Also note that `newcomp.composerWindow()` has a `hide()` and `show()` method

Answer (score 4):

The API has changed for QGIS3 :

```
from qgis.core import QgsComposition, QgsProject
composition = QgsComposition(QgsProject.instance())
composition.loadFromTemplate(template_qdoc)
```

Comment: `QgsComposition` is not available anymore in recent qgis releases

Comment: do you know to which class it was changed, @luca76?